# Prestashop: Carrier Names are not translatable anymore?

Tags: prestashop, carrier

In Prestashop 1.6.

I don't understand why the Carrier Name field is not translatable anymore.

I found serveral topics just saying that this was posible in older versions but no now. But why?

I have names like: "Standar Delivery" How are we supposed to translate these names?

Is there other approach to work with carriers and languages?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to translate carrier names and there is issue (improvement) opened in PS Forge since 1.4. I think the reason behind is that carrier usually has a name, e.g. DHL which does not need to translate.

I see in merchants' stores they use store's name as carrier. e.g. if you have Shop ABC, then carrier name would have the same name - Shop ABC.

If you have more than one carrier, e.g. `Priority Shipping`, `Standard Delivery`, etc. then it won't work. My suggestion would be to use `Standard Delivery` and below there is a field named `Transit time` which is translatable. It is actually the same as `description` so you can add short description about each carrier in different languages. Customers won't need to know which type of delivery is offered by the carrier name, they can read description next to its name.

Also it would be good to have informational (CMS) page about delivery types and costs. I would say it is a must for an online store.

Comment: I understand, PS asume that the Carriers are Shop Names, this is just wrong. Using "Standad Delivery" will have no sense if the visitor don't understand what is the meaning of those word. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I understand that this feature was enabled in previous versions. I see no reason to remove it... Weird

Comment: I think that it supposed to be a name of the carrier, like in my example, DHL, UPS, etc. which you do not translate usually, like a manufacturer name. For cases like yours it should be translatable and I agree that this functionality is missing. What I suggested is not what thinks PrestaShop, our clients just using it like this (carrier name = shop name).

Comment: No, it wasn't translatable. I haven't tested earlier versions, but at least in 1.4 there is no such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this before for PrestaShop 1.6
I know it's possible but you need to modify 2 files and you need to adjust the database.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.